# Groovy script assertion that validates the presence of some values in a JSON response

Tags: groovy, assertion, ready-api

So I'm using an testing tool called ReadyAPI and for scripting it uses the Groovy language. I'm not familiar with the language and the fact that it's based on Java it somehow makes it even worse.

Now I'm trying to validate a REST response in JSON with an assertion that checks that certain elements exist in the response.

This is the code that I have now:

```
import groovy.json.*

def response = context.expand( 'RequestResponseHere' )
def object = new JsonSlurper().parseText(response)

assert response.contains("CODE1")
assert response.contains("CODE2")
assert response.contains("CODE3")
assert response.contains("CODE4")
```

The assertion seems to work but I was wondering if there is maybe a simpler way to do it than to have to write so many lines and making it less 'bulky'?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Added an example of the json data that I have to parse:
What I need is to check that the value of "code" is always part of a list of acceptable values e.i. CODE1, CODE2, etc.

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "taskList": [
            {
                "code": "CODE1",
                "key": 123
            },
            {
                "code": "CODE2",
                "key": "234"
            },
            {
                "code": "CODE3",
                "key": "2323"
            },
            {
                "code": "CODE4",
                "key": "7829"
            },
            {
                "code": "CODE5",
                "key": "8992"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide the json response data you are asserting against. It is hard to give a concrete answer if we don't have the concrete data structure you are working against.

Comment: `["code1","code2"].each{ assert response.contains(it) }`

Comment: It looks like what @cfrick said works and it makes for a cleaner code. Thanks

Comment: @cata, in groovy you could achieve almost any syntax that looks familiar for you.

Comment: Did you mean to assert on the original response or did you mean to assert on the 'object' from the Json parsing?

Comment: No that we are seeing the actual data: what are you trying to assert? That code1-4 are there and you don't care for code5? Is the order important?

Comment: @cfrick I missed the CODE5 in my original code snippet but yes I was interested in all of the values from the "code" element. The order doesn't matter, that was just an example. Your previous example already gave me what I needed though. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to check for certain things to be there, you can DRY that
code with:

```
["code1","code2"].each{ assert response.contains(it) }
```

And as stated in the comments, if you want to make sure, "all are there,
but I don't care for the order", extracting the values and comparing it
as results can shorten this:

```
assert response._embeded.taskList*.code.toSet() == ["code1", ...].toSet()
```

Note the use of `*.`, which is the "spread operator".  It is basically
the same as `...collect{ it.code }`.  Then comparing the string sets
does the rest (this is fine if you are comparing not to many items since
the power assert will print all the items along the failed assertion; if
you have to find the proverbial needle in the haystack, you are better
off writing something smarter to check the two sets).

Answer (score 0):

> The assertion seems to work but I was wondering if there is maybe a
> simpler way to do it than to have to write so many lines and making it
> less 'bulky'?

Unclear what it is that is bulky but if what you want is to lessen the number of statements, one thing you could do is use a single `assert`.

Instead of this:

```
assert response.contains("CODE1")
assert response.contains("CODE2")
assert response.contains("CODE3")
assert response.contains("CODE4")
```

You could have this:

```
assert response.contains("CODE1") &&
       response.contains("CODE2") &&
       response.contains("CODE3") &&
       response.contains("CODE4") &&
```